# jenkins not having permission to access directories

Tags: php, jenkins

I'm attempting to set up Jenkins for my php project and i'm having permission issues. Apparently Jenkins doesn't have access to read/write files to the `build` directory that it creates. I've tried to `chmod -R 777 build` but i still get this in the Jenkins output

```
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/www/build/logs/phploc.csv): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/vendor/phploc/phploc/src/Log/CSV/Single.php on line 68
```

Here is my build.xml file. Can i do something in here to allow jenkins access to the `build` directory it's creating?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project name="mylaravel" default="build" basedir=".">
 <target name="build"
   depends="prepare,lint,phploc,pdepend,phpmd-ci,phpcs-ci,phpcpd,phpdox,phpunit,phpcb"/>

 <target name="build-parallel"
   depends="prepare,lint,tools-parallel,phpunit,phpcb"/>

 <target name="tools-parallel" description="Run tools in parallel">
  <parallel threadCount="2">
   <sequential>
    <antcall target="pdepend"/>
    <antcall target="phpmd-ci"/>
   </sequential>
   <antcall target="phpcpd"/>
   <antcall target="phpcs-ci"/>
   <antcall target="phploc"/>
   <antcall target="phpdox"/>
  </parallel>
 </target>

 <target name="clean" description="Cleanup build artifacts">
  <delete dir="${project.basedir}/build/api"/>
  <delete dir="${project.basedir}/build/code-browser"/>
  <delete dir="${project.basedir}/build/coverage"/>
  <delete dir="${project.basedir}/build/logs"/>
  <delete dir="${project.basedir}/build/pdepend"/>
 </target>

 <target name="prepare" depends="clean" description="Prepare for build">
  <mkdir dir="${project.basedir}/build/api"/>
  <mkdir dir="${project.basedir}/build/code-browser"/>
  <mkdir dir="${project.basedir}/build/coverage"/>
  <mkdir dir="${project.basedir}/build/logs"/>
  <mkdir dir="${project.basedir}/build/pdepend"/>
  <mkdir dir="${project.basedir}/build/phpdox"/>
 </target>

 <target name="lint" description="Perform syntax check of sourcecode files">
  <apply executable="php" checkreturn="1">
   <arg value="-l" />

   <fileset dir="${project.basedir}/app">
    <include name="**/*.php" />
   </fileset>

   <fileset dir="${project.basedir}/app/controllers">
    <include name="**/*.php" />
   </fileset>

   <fileset dir="${project.basedir}/app/models">
    <include name="**/*.php" />
   </fileset>

   <fileset dir="${project.basedir}/app/tests">
    <include name="**/*.php" />
   </fileset>
  </apply>
 </target>

 <target name="phploc" description="Measure project size using PHPLOC">
  <exec executable="${project.basedir}/vendor/bin/phploc" logoutput="true">
   <arg value="--log-csv" />
   <arg value="${project.basedir}/build/logs/phploc.csv" />
   <arg path="${project.basedir}/app" />
  </exec>
 </target>

 <target name="pdepend" description="Calculate software metrics using PHP_Depend">
  <exec executable="${project.basedir}/vendor/bin/pdepend" logoutput="true">
   <arg value="--jdepend-xml=${project.basedir}/build/logs/jdepend.xml" />
   <arg value="--jdepend-chart=${project.basedir}/build/pdepend/dependencies.svg" />
   <arg value="--overview-pyramid=${project.basedir}/build/pdepend/overview-pyramid.svg" />
   <arg path="${project.basedir}/app" />
  </exec>
 </target>

 <target name="phpmd"
         description="Perform project mess detection using PHPMD and print human readable output. Intended for usage on the command line before committing.">
  <exec executable="${project.basedir}/vendor/bin/phpmd" logoutput="true">
   <arg path="${project.basedir}/app" />
   <arg value="text" />
   <arg value="${project.basedir}/phpmd.xml" />
  </exec>
 </target>

 <target name="phpmd-ci" description="Perform project mess detection using PHPMD creating a log file for the continuous integration server">
  <exec executable="${project.basedir}/vendor/bin/phpmd" logoutput="true">
   <arg path="${project.basedir}/app" />
   <arg value="xml" />
   <arg value="${project.basedir}/phpmd.xml" />
   <arg value="--reportfile" />
   <arg value="${project.basedir}/build/logs/pmd.xml" />
  </exec>
 </target>

 <target name="phpcs"
         description="Find coding standard violations using PHP_CodeSniffer and print human readable output. Intended for usage on the command line before committing.">
  <exec executable="${project.basedir}/vendor/bin/phpcs" logoutput="true">
   <arg value="--standard=${project.basedir}/phpcs.xml" />
   <arg path="${project.basedir}/app" />
  </exec>
 </target>

 <target name="phpcs-ci" description="Find coding standard violations using PHP_CodeSniffer creating a log file for the continuous integration server">
  <exec executable="${project.basedir}/vendor/bin/phpcs" output="/dev/null">
   <arg value="--report=checkstyle" />
   <arg value="--report-file=${project.basedir}/build/logs/checkstyle.xml" />
   <arg value="--standard=${project.basedir}/build/phpcs.xml" />
   <arg path="${project.basedir}/app" />
  </exec>
 </target>

 <target name="phpcpd" description="Find duplicate code using PHPCPD">
  <exec executable="${project.basedir}/vendor/bin/phpcpd">
   <arg value="--log-pmd" />
   <arg value="${project.basedir}/build/logs/pmd-cpd.xml" />
   <arg path="${project.basedir}/app" />
  </exec>
 </target>

 <target name="phpdox" description="Generate API documentation using phpDox">
  <exec executable="${project.basedir}/vendor/bin/phpdox"/>
 </target>

 <target name="phpunit" description="Run unit tests with PHPUnit">
  <exec executable="${project.basedir}/vendor/bin/phpunit" logoutput="true" checkreturn="1"/>
 </target>

 <target name="phpcb" description="Aggregate tool output with PHP_CodeBrowser">
  <exec executable="${project.basedir}/vendor/bin/phpcb">
   <arg value="--log" />
   <arg path="${project.basedir}/build/logs" />
   <arg value="--source" />
   <arg path="${project.basedir}/app" />
   <arg value="--output" />
   <arg path="${project.basedir}/build/code-browser" />
  </exec>
 </target>

 <target name="install" description="Prepare files and directories for Jenkins">
    <mkdir dir="./build" />
    <mkdir dir="./generatedJUnitFiles" />

    <chown file="./build" user="jenkins.jenkins" />
    <chown file="./generatedJUnitFiles" user="jenkins.jenkins" />
 </target>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be something you're not telling us. You're using some kind of SCM (bitbucket?) to check out your code into the `${project.basedir}` before ant runs? Does the vendor folder come with the files from SCM, or do you run composer after the files have been downloaded from SCM?

You could also be using `chown -R jenkins:nogroup <files>` to change ownership of the files instead of giving all users full access to them.

**EDIT** *(i have too little karma to reply to the comment)*: If you're setting this up inside a (virtualbox) virtual machine, and Jenkins just uses your shared files, you could have some problems with permissions that you may not be able to fix using either `chmod` or `chown`. You should use the following mount command to mount the shared folder:

```
mount -t vboxsf -o uid=${UID},gid=${GID} <shared folder> <target>
```

Where ${UID} is the uid of the jenkins user, and ${GID} is the group id of the `nogroup` group (usually 65534).

If you're using vagrant, you should have a look at [this](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/897) or [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/398414/vagrant-set-default-share-permissions).

Comment: I am using BitBucket but the way i have it set up now is Jenkins looks at my local files. It doesn't go through BitBucket to check out code. It just looks like at what i already have.